# PHP - Order a list of database elements

Tags: php, mysql

I am displaying a list of items based on a database. The order of the items is by `ProductID`.

When I add an item to the database, it is automatically assigned a `ProductID`.

However, I would like to be able to either

- a) sort the list alphabetically by name, without changing the `ProductID` in the database or
- b) add another column to the database called, for example: `Rank`, and have this list display the list by `Rank`, rather than by `ProductID`.

Here is my code. Any help in re-writing this section of the code to accomplish either a) or b) would be very helpful!

PS: I'm a little familiar with PHP and databases, but I am by no means an experienced coder.

```
$category = array_search(strtolower('upright'), $CFG["Category"]);
$product2 = new ProductData();
$where2 = sprintf(" WHERE CategoryID=%d ORDER BY ProductID DESC", $category);
$rows2 = $product2->GetRows($where2);

$count2 = count($rows2);
$line_count2 = 4;
$total_lines2 = ceil($count2/$line_count2);

// Photo
$photo5 = new PhotoData();

$thumb_array5 = array();
$count3 = count($rows2);
for ( $i = 0; $i < $count3; $i++ )
{
    $ret = $photo5->Query($rows2[$i]["ProductID"]);
    if ( $ret != 0 )
    {
        continue;
    }

    $thumb_array5[$photo5->Get("ProductID")] = $photo5->Get("Photo1");
}
```

Comment: So to clarify you want to change the order they are displayed in the database according to what criteria? And this is purely for display in the database or you're displaying this list on a page? If its the former, that's a matter of setting a primary key on the column in the Database, if it's the latter it's a matter of changing your SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

Your `SELECT` query is not shown which I assume is coming from your `ProductData()` class. If you could change the source of your `ProductData()` that includes ranking, you could use a variable for ranking, like:

```
 SELECT  
      @Ranking := @Ranking + 1 AS Rank,
      productID,
      product_name
 FROM   yourTable t, (SELECT @Ranking := 0) r
 ORDER BY  product_name;
```

Otherwise you could do it in your `Php` instead:

First change the ORRDER BY to your product name instead of product id:

```
$category = array_search(strtolower('upright'), $CFG["Category"]);
$product2 = new ProductData();
$where2 = sprintf(" WHERE CategoryID=%d ORDER BY Product_Name", $category);
```

Then in your php use a variable to do the ranking:

```
 $count3 = count($rows2);
 echo "<table><tr><th>Ranking</th><th>Product Name</th><th>Product Name</th></tr>";
 for ( $rank = 0; $rank < $count3; $rank++ )
 {
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>$rank+1</td><td>".$rows2[$rank]["Product_name"]."</td><td><img src='".$photo5->Get("Photo1")."'></td>"
   echo "</tr>";
 }
 echo "</table>";
```

Comment: I believe this second option, the PHP option, does what it already is doing. That code still sorts by the most recently added item, rather than by the "rank" characteristic. How do I pull from the database by the non-primary column?

Comment: What is the criteria of your ranking? Is it ordered by product name or something else?

Comment: @Pianosman:see my update above and if not correct answer my question above regarding criteria.